# If else in Where Clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I faced a problem with a SQL query. I have a table with 10 fields.
I need to create a query, which gets date by field ProductionYear(int) between 2 variables @startDate(int) and @endDate(int). Both of these variables are unnecessary. And I need to build a SQL query with following conditions:

```
If(@endDate = 0)
Select Id from MyTable where ProductionYear > @startDate
else
Select Id from MyTable where ProductionYear BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate.
```

How can I build a query with those conditions?

Comment: FYI The choice of types vs names of `ProductionYear`, `@startDate` and `@endDate` seems odd. They all seem INT (based on the first `IF`) but I would *hate* to encounter a variable **@blablaDate** that is NOT of type `Date` or `DateTime(2)`. You might want to rethink this.

Comment: While this is a common question/problem, generally it's best to create one stored procedure or dynamic SQL per case.  The optimiser tends to get caught up with whatever plan it experiences first and applies that to subsequent invocations.  That's not always optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can incorporate this into a single query:

```
Select Id
from MyTable
where ProductionYear >= @startDate and
      (ProductionYear <= @endDate or @endDate = 0);
```

Your two queries are inconsistent on whether `@startDate` is included.  `BETWEEN` includes the comparison values, but `>` does not.

If you want `@startDate` to also be optional:

```
Select Id
from MyTable
where (ProductionYear >= @startDate or @startDate = 0) and
      (ProductionYear <= @endDate or @endDate = 0);
```

Some additional comments.  Calling a "year" a "date" is confusing.  Your parameters should probably be called `@startYear` and `@endYear`.

These queries are going to result in full table scans of your table.  This is probably not a big deal, because the granularity is by year.  If the granularity were more refined, you might want to use an index.  In that case, perhaps the best approach is dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using case when

```
  Select Id from MyTable 
    where ProductionYear BETWEEN (case when @startDate>@endDate then @endDate
 else @startDate  end) and 
(case when @startDate>@endDate then @startDate else @endDate end)
```